# Android alertdialogue builder returning boolean

Tags: android

I've already pst this earlier too, but somehow that was freezes. so Doing a duplicate one.

I am wring a simple script where there is a confirmation box of two options. I need to cal it more than one time in an activity. So i made a method to do that. Based on the returning boolean i want to write the conditional statements.

```
// Before oncreate
```

static boolean confirmation;

```
 private void showConfirmation() {
        // UserFunctions userFunctions = null;
        // TODO Auto-generated methodastub

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("test");
        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please update the unfilled fields.").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                        confirmation = false;

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Later on", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        confirmation = true;
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();

}    









public void myOnClicktest(View v) {

    showConfirmation();
    if (confirmation){ 

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: your method return type is void it should be boolean if you want to return true or false

Answer (score 1):

Do like this-

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please update the unfilled fields.").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                        confirmation = false;

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Later on", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),   NewActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Because in your case your code will not wait for confirmation value to change in dialog box it skip dialog, by default confirmation value is false.

Comment: But the setNegativeButton will not only start the activity, it will be called for many other tasks. Basically i need to call showConfirmation() to perform different task.

Comment: your code will not wait for confirmation value to change in dialog box it skip it, by default confirmation value is false.

Comment: So could you suggest me any way out?

Comment: whatever other task you want to execute, write in separate method. and call that method from dialog box. even your whole code depend on that.

Comment: If it helped you then dont forget to vote it up,, if it solved your prob then accept this as well.